# Faceting on Pie Charts in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Simple question, but I'm a novice in R so it's giving me a bit of consternation. I'm trying to make a number of pie charts in R to practice my data visualization skills.

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   carrier n_cancelled n_early n_ontime n_late
     <chr>       <int>   <int>    <int>  <int>
1       9E        1044      54    12891   4471
2       AA         636      16    26965   5112
3       AS           2      12      606     94
4       B6         466     155    41661  12353
5       DL         349      36    39931   7794
6       EV        2817      66    35646  15644
7       F9           3       1      489    192
8       FL          73      16     2321    850
9       HA           0       1      317     24
10      MQ        1234      53    19790   5320
11      OO           3       0       23      6
12      UA         686      22    45762  12195
13      US         663       9    17444   2420
14      VX          31       7     4231    893
15      WN         192       0     8833   3250
16      YV          56       2      387    156
```

What I'm looking for is a number of pie charts like the below for each carrier.

[image: looks like this]

Right now I have code that looks like this...

```
status <- c("Cancelled", "Early", "On-Time", "Late")
ggplot(counts_by_carrier, aes(x = factor(1), y = c(n_cancelled, n_early, n_ontime, n_late), fill = status)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  blank_theme + 
  facet_grid(facets=. ~ carrier)
```

But it returns `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (16): x, y, fill`

Which makes sense as an error. I'm feeding it as a Y value a vector of all the values n_cancelled, etc. and it doesn't know how to handle that for a single piechart.

But how I fix it is currently beyond me. How do I force it to look at only one row at a time and print a different one for every row?

Comment: Pictures aren't code/data and there was info provided on the question page (and in the SO R FAQ/tag page) for how to include data with your example. Waffle charts or simple bar charts may also be a better way to go.

Comment: You need to convert your data to long format first. Use `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::gather`, for example. `Carrier` is your id-column (don't melt that one). Then, only supply the single remaining value column as y and the variable column as x. facet by carrier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to post your data in a format that people can actually *use* to help you, e.g.,:

```
df <- read.table(
  text = 
"   carrier n_cancelled n_early n_ontime n_late
1       9E        1044      54    12891   4471
2       AA         636      16    26965   5112
3       AS           2      12      606     94
4       B6         466     155    41661  12353
5       DL         349      36    39931   7794
6       EV        2817      66    35646  15644
7       F9           3       1      489    192
8       FL          73      16     2321    850
9       HA           0       1      317     24
10      MQ        1234      53    19790   5320
11      OO           3       0       23      6
12      UA         686      22    45762  12195
13      US         663       9    17444   2420
14      VX          31       7     4231    893
15      WN         192       0     8833   3250
16      YV          56       2      387    156"
)
```

As @docendo commented, you will need to convert the data to "long" format, e.g, like this using `dplyr`/`tidyr`:

```
df %>%
  gather("Outcome", "Count", - carrier)
```

Which will now have only three columns -- the column headers will become the entries in "Outcome", and the values will become the counts, like so:

```
  carrier     Outcome Count
1      9E n_cancelled  1044
2      AA n_cancelled   636
3      AS n_cancelled     2
4      B6 n_cancelled   466
5      DL n_cancelled   349
6      EV n_cancelled  2817
```

Then, you can pass that information to ggplot to make the plot you want (note that I am removing the leading "n_" from each group):

```
df %>%
  gather("Outcome", "Count", - carrier) %>%
  mutate(Outcome = gsub("^n_","", Outcome)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = Outcome
             , y = Count
             , x = 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity"
           , position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~carrier
             , scales = "free_y") +
  xlab("")
```

[image]

I will **not** make this a pie chart however (though you can likely convert to that easily). They are almost never a good idea, and if your goal is to improve your data visualization, I would strongly recommend against using pie charts.